# How to change state of circuit breaker for testing purpose using springboot code

Tags: java, spring-boot, prometheus, circuit-breaker, resilience4j

I have a requirement to generate a prometheus alert if state my resilience4j circuit breaker changes to Open.
In order to test it, I want to change its state forcefully. Like I can create a test Rest API which can take circuit breaker and state which I want to set. ex : "/changeState/myBreaker/open". (myBreaker is CB name and open is the state).

Is there a way to achieve this in springboot code?

Comment: Hi, I added an answer to the question please consider to upvote and approve it as answer if it address your requirements cause it took around 1 hour of my time :) otherwise feel free to leave comment if you need more help.

Answer (score 1):

> How to change state of [resilience4j](https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs) circuit breaker ? (Native Resilience4j)

You can simply change the state programmatically using the CircuitBreaker interface, for the spring variant check the next, begin by creating a circuit breaker with suitable constructor or static builder that suits you, the call `transitionToOpenState()`.

```
CircuitBreaker circuitBreaker = CircuitBreaker.ofDefaults("myCircuitBreaker");

circuitBreaker.transitionToOpenState();
...
circuitBreaker.transitionToHalfOpenState();
circuitBreaker.transitionToClosedState();

...
```

> How to change state of [resilience4j](https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs) circuit breaker with spring for testing purpose? (Mockito and Spring bean injection)

First add the proper version of [Resilence4j](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.resilience4j) and [Mockito](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-core) dependencies to you `.pom` file.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>resilience4j-spring-boot2</artifactId>
  <version>'suitable-version'</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
  <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
  <version>'suitable-version'</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Then create a circuit breaker singleton bean with desired configuration in the spring IOC context.

```
@Bean
public CircuitBreaker lunaticCircuitBreaker() {
  CircuitBreakerConfig circuitBreakerConfig = CircuitBreakerConfig.custom()
    .failureRateThreshold(30)
    .waitDurationInOpenState(Duration.ofMillis(5000))
    ...
    .build();

  return CircuitBreaker.of("lunaticCircuitBreaker", circuitBreakerConfig);
}
```

In the test file, mock the circuit breaker and call `thenReturn()` to define the behavior of the circuit breaker method when it is called some thing like previous quote we had.

```
@MockBean
private CircuitBreaker lunaticCircuitBreaker;

...
```

```html
Mockito.when(lunaticCircuitBreaker.transitionToOpenState()).thenReturn(null);
```

Then just invoke the method that calls the circuit breaker in your code.

```
someService.someMethod(...);
Mockito.verify(lunaticCircuitBreaker, Mockito.times(1)).transitionToOpenState();
```

Also note that changing the state of a circuit breaker programmatically should be used with caution, cause it affect the behavior of system. It's generally recommended to rely on the **automatic state transitions** provided by Resilience4j.